# How to Flutter container error full width?

Tags: flutter, dart, position

Hello I am new on flutter and I would like my container to take all the width of its parent but I get an error when adding width: double.infinite

I was able to browse the forum for a solution but most of them are about row and don't work for me.

I get the following error:
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView

I would like my container with a red color to take the whole width

my code :

```
child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: series?.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (item, index) {
                        return Container(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color:
                                    const Color.fromRGBO(205, 205, 205, 1)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 216, 216, 216)
                                    .withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                blurRadius: 3,
                                offset: Offset(
                                    0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 150,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(078),
                                  ),
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8)),
                                    ),
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      series![index].thumbUrl,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 83, 30, 30),
                                        height: 150,
                                        child: Text("hhh"))
                                  ])
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMRse.png)

I have already tried to use Expanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (item, index) {
              return Container(
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  border:
                      Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(205, 205, 205, 1)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color:
                          Color.fromARGB(255, 216, 216, 216).withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 2,
                      blurRadius: 3,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(078),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8)),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(Icons.star))),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 83, 30, 30),
                          height: 150,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text("hhh"),
                            ],
                          )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
```

[image]

Comment: thank you can you explain to me what you have done?